# same file different size in Linux and AIX

Tags: linux, aix

we have file in Linux and copied to AIX. same file smaller size in AIX.

Linux - ext3 file system
AIX - jfs2 file system

both file systems in same block size 4k

```
size in Linux
     du -sk p14727347_112030_AIX64-5L.zip
    1160568 p14727347_112030_AIX64-5L.zip
Size in AIX    
      du -sk p14727347_112030_AIX64-5L.zip
    1159484 p14727347_112030_AIX64-5L.zip
```

Any idea why its different

Comment: No copy problem? If you copy the file back (to a different name) then it "becomes larger" again? Or have you checked hash values?

Comment: Agree with @HaukeLaging - check to see if the files' md5s match.

Comment: How did you copy it?

Comment: I use scp to copy the file, we notied this on multiple file. if I copy it back its bigger in linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing from my `du(1)` manual here (Fedora 18, coreutils-8.17-8.fc18):

```
du - estimate file space usage
```

There is a flag `--apparent-size`, that prints out (an approximation to) the space usage by the file, excluding extra space that the filesystem uses.

So, `du` *estimates* the space on disk used by the file, i.e., data blocks and metadata. AIX and Linux presumably are using different filesystems, the space used by metadata doesn't have to be the same.

Compare the output of `ls -l` for both files, that gives the length of the file itself.

Comment: stat and istat give same size Length. linux Size: 1187252238, AIX 1187252238 bytes
Thanks

Comment: OK, mistery solved then.